# Insert a comma between Arabic(Persian) and English words in a text using Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, arabic-support, farsi

I have a txt file which contains 32000 lines. The data is in Arabo-Persian, however, each line contains the Roman transcription of the first word.

> دێان diêyan بنووڕه‌ ‌دگان نگا دگان‌

> دێان‌ شكنه diêyan şêkêne دگان‌ شكنه

> دیدن dîdin بنووڕه‌ ‌دید نگا دید و تركیباتش

I need to put a comma before and after the Roman transcription. I have written this, but it puts a comma after every characters of the Roman transcription:

```
import re

output = open("output.txt","w")
input = open("sample.txt").read()

for word in input:
    output.write(re.sub(r'^([a-z])', r',\1', word))


output.close()
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try

`re.sub('([a-z].*[a-z])', r',\1,', word)`

Output File:

```
دێان ,diêyan, بنووڕه‌ ‌دگان نگا دگان‌

دێان‌ شكنه ,diêyan şêkêne, دگان‌ شكنه

دیدن ,dîdin, بنووڕه‌ ‌دید نگا دید و تركیباتش
```

But the word has to start and end with [a-z].

Comment: It didn't work. ê is not Roman, but it is not important because it comes in the middle of the word. We only need to mark the beginning and end of the words.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
re.sub(r'(([a-zêîş]+ ?)+)', r',\1', word))
```

it will produce the following output for the sample text you've provided:

```
دێان ,diêyan بنووڕه‌ ‌دگان نگا دگان‌
دێان‌ شكنه ,diêyan şêkêne دگان‌ شكنه
دیدن ,dîdin بنووڕه‌ ‌دید نگا دید و تركیباتش
```

You'll need to add any special characters you might have in the pattern.